# Intent does not work in on click function

Tags: android-intent

I am trying to move from one activity to another using Intents. The intent object is fired on a function but its not working then application crashed whenever i pushes the button.

firstActivity class bt_open function

```
 public void bt_Open(View v)
    {

        Intent i= new Intent(Map.this,FileChooser.class);
        startActivity(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I remove the LinearLayout tag in the layout of ListActivity and then it work perfectly

Comment: A ListActivity is based on a ListView. ListView must be the parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `FileChooser` activity in the Manifest.xml? Every activity should be defined in `Manifest.xml`.

Comment: Yeah it is defined in manifest file but the issue is this filechooser is List activity so i wanted to know how to start Listactivity from an intent?

Comment: There is no difference starting a ListActivity from starting other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Are Map and FileChooser the appropriate activity names (e.g. no typos)?

The following should work:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Map.this, FileChooser.class));
```

and in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FileChooser" />
<activity
    android:name=".Map />
```

Comment: sir FileChooser is List activity thats why it is now working. so i wanted to know how to start List activity from an intent

Comment: Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html for more information on ListActivity.